# How to increase and decrease rowheight of tableview cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode8

I have tableview cell with question view, each question contains three option notes view, images view and Actions items view. A cell contains more button.Using this more button, I have to (show/hide) notes view, images view, action item views, by default cell load with question view.

Comment: Check this http://www.atomicbird.com/blog/uistackview-table-cells

Comment: @Rajesh This works wonderfully. But will only work for devices which have iOS 9 and above (because of stack view).

Answer (score 0):

for expand and colapse `tableviewcell`

```
var selectedIndex = ""
```

add below lines in your `viewDidLoad`

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300 //give maximumheight you expect in tableviewcell
```

set NotesView height constraint outlet to UITableViewCell

add this line to your `cellForRowAt`

```
cell.moreBtn.tag = indexPath.row
cell.moreBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.moreClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

if selectedIndex == "\(indexPath.row)" {
cell.notesViewHgt.constant = 100 //give height you required
} else {
cell.noteViewHgt.constant = 0
}
```

then add this function into your viewcontroller

```
func moreClicked(_ sender:UIButton){
self.selectedIndex = "\(sender.tag)"
self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: If you consider that your problem is solved, you can accept answer, this will mark the question as answered. Cheers!